# Email goes to spam because of "HTML Obfuscation"

Tags: php, html-email, swiftmailer, email-spam

According to the spam-test available at [this link](http://www.contactology.com/check_mqs.php) -- The automated, "Thank you for signing up" emails are going into the spam folder because :

```
SPAM: BODY: Message is 10% to 20% HTML obfuscation (-32)
```

However, I can't find anything that explains what that means -

I'm using SwiftMailer, and this is the relevant code that I use to set the headers / add the HTML part :

[...]
    $body_txt = strip_tags($body); 
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

```
$typeone = $message -> getHeaders() -> get('MIME-Version');
$typeone -> setValue('1.0');

$typetwo = $message -> getHeaders() -> get('Content-Type');
$typetwo -> setValue('text/html');
$typetwo -> setParameter('charset', 'utf-8');

$message -> setSubject($subject)
         -> setFrom(array("courier@".TRIMMED_DOMAIN => HUMAN_READABLE_URL))  
         -> setTo($to)
         -> setBody($body_txt)
         -> addPart($body, 'text/html');
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(TRIMMED_URL, 25)
                -> setUsername("courier@".TRIMMMED_URL)
                -> setPassword(MAILER_PASSWORD); 
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer -> send($message);
```

And the email, itself, with lots of text omitted:
(Perhaps we are using too much HTML?)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Thank you for Joining [the website]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1> Welcome!</h1>
            <p>
                Thank you for joining [our] community.
            </p>
            <h2>%s</h2><!-- this gets run through sprintf() and ultimately winds up being an <a> -->
            %s
            <p>
                Our goal is to connect you [ blah, blah, blah ]
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    [each of these contains a <strong> tag]
                </li>
                <li>[text omitted..] 
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
                <li>
            </li>
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                    If you have any questions, comments, concerns, or suggestions,
 feel free to send us a message on our Contact Page.



            We sincerely appreciate your feedback.

                Constructive input from our community members helps us continually improve the [ ] experience.

                Thank you again for joining [our] community.


            </p>
            <p>
                Sincerely,
            </p>
            <p>
                <em>The [...] Team.</em>
            </p>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So if anyone can give me any insight at all on what is triggering this `HTML obfuscation` flag, then I would greatly appreciate it.

### EDIT:

---

Also, I forgot to mention that viewing the email source shows a bunch of `=09`'s :

```
=09=09=09=09We sincerely ap=
preciate your feedback.

=09=09=09=09Constructive input from our commun=
ity members helps us continually improve the[]experience.=
```

Comment: would have to see a whole actual email

Comment: Uh, well, that's pretty much it, there... I figured the content was irrelevant to a flag that says "HTML Obfuscation" - 
But, I'll put more of the original text back in there... 
Although, I think the only keyword is "Free"

Comment: i call B.S on that checker, its overly sensitive so they can sell their crap

Comment: Remember that there is no one spam detection program, and that every mail server will have a different configuration.

Comment: Well, yeah, but that was the best place I could start. And while I thought we had crafted this to the best of "not-spam" standards - it seems kinda hopeless.

Comment: test it, real world, send to gmail\yahoo\ your isp, check the headers of the received mail for any spamscore\report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the message you're getting they're just running it through SpamAssassin, which has an entry for that specific warning on their [wiki page](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018172330/http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/HTML_OBFUSCATE_10_20) (archive.org)

and explains it to be because of

> The message includes HTML with obfuscated text, such as unnecessary hex-encoding of ASCII characters. This is probably an attempt to avoid text-based filters

While I can't see any reason for that to be triggered by the part of your e-mail that you pasted, maybe there's something about it in the parts that were omitted?
Hope this helps.

### EDIT AFTER ORIGINAL POST WAS EDITED FOR ADDITIONAL INFO:

the =09 characters you're seeing represent tabs in ascii.

Generally speaking html emails are somewhat of a challenging beast by itself and most of the knowledge I could contribute are way outside the scope of this specific question, but to provide some general additional help, which i hope will be applicable to your situation:

for maximum compatibility always use the following header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This is because some email clients and/or providers in their web interface will actually strip your doctype and replace them with the one you see above - this way you optimize for it. The meta tag in the head forces the encoding to utf-8 which is always helpful.

Try to not have any whitespace, at least, within your tags - as stated above the `=09` you're seeing are due to the tabs you're using.

If you need a separation of paragraphs, close the `</p>` and open a new one.

For example:

```
<p>lorem ipsum whateverrrrrrrrr</p>
<br>
<p>another paragraph</p>
```

Don't try to simulate vertical spacing with whitespace, you'll run into tons of trouble.
(Don't use `<br>` within `<p>`'s either to force a break unless you want gmail to make the following text *purple* [this is not a joke])

Comment: Golden - Minifying the HTML (and removing the tabs) killed the spam-score on that test. So, hopefully that does the trick, all-around -

Comment: i'm glad it helped! :) i was actually wrestling with myself on how much to write to provide help without going completely off-topic